# Enable "Return Recipient Auto Responded Status" in Connect/API

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using a sandbox account to test DocuSign API along with DocuSign Connect.

When I send an envelope to an undeliverable address, the sender receives a DocuSign email saying that it could not be delivered, however my webhook does not receive any event (all events for both envelope and recipients are enabled from DocuSign Connect settings).

I've read that there is an account-level setting to enable Auto Responded status, that I cannot enable on my own. Is this option available for sandbox accounts? How can I contact a DocuSign administrator?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your sandbox account by default all notifications are set at envelope level meaning every envelope event will be reported. If you decide to disable it you will receive grouped notifications only eg Send/Completed. You can turn on/off by going to Settings -> Updates. The first one "Send Individual Messages" should be enabled for sandbox accounts.
You are correct that for production account needs to be enabled through the back-end

### Update

Regarding the failed deliveries, you are correct this needs to be set on our backend. When set in your notification you will see

```
<Status>AutoResponded</Status>
```

which indicates the email bounced back.
If you like this setting to be switched on email to go-live@docusign.com with case ref: 06841999